# Trying to display a <List> into a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have an Object which has data in it, now I need to put that data into a ListBox.
What is the best way to do that. The data is a List but no matter what I do I can't get the List to go into the ListBox. I have read about ToString() but not sure how to do that. I know this is a little vague, but its the best I can do.

The CollectionClass creates a list which inputs the data into and Ingredient object, The I need to get the Ingredient object to display in the List

```
    CollectionClass newCollection = new CollectionClass();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        newCollection.createList();
        List<Ingredient > myIngredientDisplay = new List<Ingredient>();


        listBoxIngredients.DataSource = myIngredientDisplay;

    }
```

Comment: Is your list `List<string>`? If not is it filled with objects where `ToString` would be valid for ex. classes that implements it or value types? However the approach is simple, just loop through the list and call `Add`

Comment: Do you have a code snippet you can show?

Comment: There's no way to answer this without knowing what your object looks like and which property you want to display in the ListBox.

Comment: The <List> is filled with Objects. How do I implement the ToString()?

Comment: You could post the code instead of describing it

Comment: Does that help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if you can provide structure of class (class of object you are using), then it would be easy for us,
I am assuming you are having a class in which you have a property of type List say "String_List"

```
class TestClass
    {
     public List<string> String_List{ get  ; set; }
    }
```

Now to use it we need to create its object.

TestClass ObjClass = new TestClass();

I hope these all things are done already in your code.
Now you need to access each list item through for or foreach loop and then you can add items to list.

```
foreach (string i in ObjClass.String_List)
        { listBox1.Items.Add(i); }
```